# Can't prevent refresh even though using ajax to submit form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, liferay, portlet

I'm writing a portlet function in order to upload an excel file to the back-end for handling.

And I wish that the page does not refresh and allows me to change the page after a successful upload.

I tried to use ajax to upload the file, but it's not working.

html part

```
<portlet:actionURL var="uploadWorkbook" name="uploadWorkbook"></portlet:actionURL>
<b>Please Upload a Document</b> 

 <form id = "UploadExcelForm" name ="UploadExcelForm" action="<%=uploadWorkbook%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">
<button type="submit"> Upload </button>
</form>
```

ajax part,

```
$("#UploadExcelForm").on('submit', (function(e) {
   if ($('#uploadedFile').val().trim().length == 0) {
        alert("Please choose a file!");
        return false;
    }else{
            $.ajax({
            url: uploadWorkbook,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: $('#UploadExcelForm').serialize(),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(){}
        })
        e.preventDefault();
}
}));
```

back-end part (how to get the uploaded file)

```
public void uploadWorkbook(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception{
        boolean submit = true;
        boolean success = false;
        UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest); 
        String uploadedTemplateId = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("templateId");

        File uploadedFile = uploadPortletRequest.getFile("uploadedFile", true); 
//to do sth on file...
}
```

Comment: try to move `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning and to `return false` in both the cases, so outside `if/else`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers give you some hints on the JS side, which you should follow. On the portal side, you're posting to `<portlet:actionURL/>`, which will return a fully rendered page (and might even be intercepted by Liferay's SPA framework - though I'm not sure about it handling explicit ajax calls.

If you just want to return a result for your file upload (e.g. a status, JSON, etc), you probably want to post to `<portlet:resourceURL/>`, and handle it in a resource-handler on the Java side, instead of an action-handler.

Posting to a resource handler will not render all of the other portlets on the page, while an action handler will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the form tag and remove type submit from your button.

Answer (score 0):

Change from `type="submit"`:

```
<button type="submit"> Upload </button>
```

to:

```
<button> Upload </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `action` from the form tag.

Then instead of `e.preventDefault()`, use `return false` and put it outside of the `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
<button type="submit"> Upload </button>
```

to

```
<button type="button"> Upload </button>
```

And put

```
e.preventDefault();
```

out side if condition (so it executes for both)